# Reading from text files and printing contents c++

Tags: c++, constructor, text-files

I've been told to read/write disc as little as possible. For this solution, I've made a constructor that reads the file on object construction and fills the unordered map with the contents of the file. Is this a good way/practice to read from .txt files?

In terms of printing out the contents of the file, I've mentioned readFile again. Is this ok to do? I couldn't really find another way without making it global. Here is the code below:

```
class Test {
private:
    string name;
    string number;
    unordered_map<string, string> mappy;
public:

Test()
{
    ifstream readFile("A:\\Coding\\namesNumbers.txt");

    while (readFile >> name >> number)
    {
        mappy[name] = number;
    }
}

void print()
{
    ifstream readFile("A:\\Coding\\namesNumbers.txt");

    while (readFile >> name >> number)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            cout << name << ":" << " ";
            cout << number << endl;
        }
    }
}

~Test() {};

};
```

Comment: Since you've read the file contents in the constructor, what's the point of reading them again in the print routine? Print out what you read earlier.

Comment: If the question is just whethe reading a file in a constructor is a good practice, the answer is that is depend on the context. It is a *design* decision and without any context, I cannot says whether it is a good or bad.

Comment: `name`/`number` should be local variables.

Comment: Why this "loop" `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` (which runs once).

Comment: You make a valid point Jarod42. I just tried it without the loop by just printing it and it does the same thing.

Comment: user4581301 if I don't read the file again in the print function, the program won't run as it won't have anything to read without it. I've already tried this. Unless I make the readFile global I can't see another way

Comment: @Oxic Just print contents of `mappy`.

Comment: `A:` ? What century are we in? :)

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the file twice. When you don't mind the order of the items, then you can also print from 'mappy'.

Note that it is better to declare 'name' and 'number' as local as possible.

(Consider using another data type for 'number' i.s.o. 'string'.)

In the code below, I assume you have C++17 (for Structured binding)

```
class Test {
private:
    unordered_map<string, string> mappy;
public:

    Test()
    {
        ifstream readFile("A:\\Coding\\namesNumbers.txt");
        string name;
        string number;
        while (readFile >> name >> number)
        {
            mappy[name] = number;
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        for (auto [name, number] : mappy)
        {
            cout << name << ":" << " ";
            cout << number << endl;
        }
    }

    ~Test() {};

};
```

Reading a file in a construct is not necessarily a bad practice. Depends on the intended usage of the class. Sometimes you need to separate (default) construction from the reading of the data. In such a case you can provide two constructors: one for default construction and one for construction with file reading. As long as your solution satisfies, you can stick to that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Name and Number are undefined. I think it's because were declaring the variables within the function.